# Как отобразить все уникальные элементы списка и их количество по убыванию?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, сортировка, counter

Дан список: `data=[пр1, пр1, пр1, пр1, пр2, пр2, пр3]`. Требуется получить на выходе отсортированные по убыванию данные в виде:

```
4 пр1 
2 пр2
1 пр3
```

Сначала пыталась использовать Counter. Вывелось так же, как требуется, но не было сортировки, поэтому решение не подошло. Может есть способ отсортировать элементы в этом случае?

```
from collections import Counter
c=Counter(data)
for i in c:
    print(c[i],i)
```

Следующей попыткой пробовала так:

```
data1=set(data)
data2=list(data1)
c1=data.count('пр1')
c2=data.count('пр2')
c3=data.count('пр3')
f=[c1,c2,c3]
```

Так в data2 остались только уникальные элементы. В f хранятся значения количества повторяющихся элементов в исходном списке. Надо как-то соединить их правильно. Пыталась с помощью zip, но видимо плохо пыталась. А ещё отсортировать и вывести в столбик. То есть мне бы получить вот такой список: `[(4, 'пр1'), (2, 'пр2'), (1, 'пр3')]`. И при выводе с помощью `print(*d, sep = "\n")` избавиться от скобок.

Comment: по какому ключу необходимо отсоритровать ? по количеству этого значения или по самому значению ?

Answer (score 4):

Метод `.most_common()` (примерно переводится как "самые частые") объекта `Counter` возвращает ключи-значения в порядке убывания значения (т.е. количества), так что тут можно обойтись без явной сортировки:

```
from collections import Counter

data = ["пр1", "пр1", "пр1", "пр1", "пр2", "пр2", "пр3"]

counter = Counter(data)
print(counter.most_common())
```

Вывод: `[('пр1', 4), ('пр2', 2), ('пр3', 1)]`

Если нужно в каждой паре выводить сначала количество, потом сам элемент, то через list comprehension можно поменять их местами:

```
inverted = [(value, key) for key, value in counter.most_common()]
print(inverted)
```

Вывод: `[(4, 'пр1'), (2, 'пр2'), (1, 'пр3')]`

Comment: точно, классный вариант !)

Comment: @Dmitry ну технически внутри все равно сортировка вызывается https://i.stack.imgur.com/BW8bX.png, разница будет только если n самых частых нужно получить, тогда без полной сортировки вытаскивает нужное количество через ["кучу"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0_(%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)).

Comment: Спасибо большое! теперь буду знать про замечательный метод .most_common()

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, вы что-то не так пробовали.

```
from collections import Counter

data = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'b']

data = Counter(data)
data = [(value, key,) for key, value in data.items()]
data.sort(reverse=True)

print(data)

>> [(3, 'b'), (2, 'a'), (1, 'c')]
```

Ну а дальше можете делать с этим списком что угодно.